# How to store richtextbox content directly to ftp in C#?

Tags: c#, ftp

Guys this the code to store file on ftp. Can any one reconfigure this code so that it stores the contents of the richtextbox in windows forms I'm writing anything on richtextbox when I click button it should store directly ftp.

```
{
    Stream requestStream = null;
    FileStream fileStream = null;
    FtpWebResponse uploadResponse = null;
    try
    {
        uploadUrl = "ftp://ftp.personalwebars.com/ATM/";
        fileName = txtTitle.Text + ".txt";
        FtpWebRequest uploadRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uploadUrl + @"/" + fileName);
        uploadRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        //Since the FTP you are downloading to is secure, send
        //in user name and password to be able upload the file
        ICredentials credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pswd);
        uploadRequest.Credentials = credentials;
        //UploadFile is not supported through an Http proxy
        //so we disable the proxy for this request.
        uploadRequest.Proxy = null;
        //uploadRequest.UsePassive = false; <--found from another forum and did not make a difference
        requestStream = uploadRequest.GetRequestStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while (true)
        {
            bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            if (bytesRead == 0)
                break;
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        //The request stream must be closed before getting
        //the response.
        requestStream.Close();
        uploadResponse =
          (FtpWebResponse)uploadRequest.GetResponse();
        lblAuthentication.Text = "Your solution has been submitted in txt Mode. Thank You";
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        if (uploadResponse != null)
            uploadResponse.Close();
        if (fileStream != null)
            fileStream.Close();
        if (requestStream != null)
            requestStream.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're looking for `StreamWriter`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, extract the string from the text box and pass it in as the content parameter,

```
public void Send(string url, string fileName, string content, string user, string password)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content)
    var request = (FtpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url + @"/" + fileName));
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    request.UsePassive = false;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password);
    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    requestStream.Close();
    var response = (FtpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
    if (response != null) response.Close();
}
```